# WHMCS: Order Accept Encountered Problems- Curl error: couldn't connect to host Url

Tags: php, curl, whmcs

For the past four hours I have been trying to configure TCAdmin to work with whmcs. I set up the server in the server setting of WHMCS and added all the configurable options. I got my first demo order and when I select "Accept Order" I get this error:

Order Accept Encountered Problems
Curl error: couldn't connect to host Url: http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8880/billingapi.aspx

For some reason WHMCS can't connect, but when I connect I get this: "Visit http://help.tcadmin.com for help". I tried that. Still no luck.

So I went into my server, found the billingapi.aspx file and it said this:
    This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!"

Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions? All help is appreciated :)

-Max

Answer (score 0):

Curl is failing to connect but you think it should be able to? There are a few things to check:

- Is the address being passed to Curl *really* right? (It's *so* easy to get this wrong!)
- Is the target host reachable from the host making the request (the origin)? Firewall rules can cause all sorts of strange problems here. Check if you can do a read-only request from the origin and get through that way.
- Is the target *port* on the target host accessible from the origin? Again, it's the firewall, and port `8880` is not one that I'd expect to normally be a permitted outgoing target in an aggressive firewall regime; a specific rule may well be needed.
- Is there a problem with DNS? Hopefully not, but if name resolution itself keeps failing then that might be a significant issue. (This won't be the case if you use an IP address instead of a DNS host name, but that can cause the request to fail in other ways — such as if the target hosts many sites — so don't jump to conclusions here.)

Other problems that are theoretically possible (e.g., bad request contents, wrong path in the URL) would give different error messages.

Comment: My money is on a firewall problem. Those are features of a deployment — the Ops side of DevOps — and a developer can't easily tackle them from elsewhere.